# Add angular-chart.js to Rails application.js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-chart

I'm trying to setup `angular-chart.js` in an Angular on Rails application, per github instructions. But the documentation is not specifically for Rails so I'm running into errors.

Installation instruction: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

For reference,

1. installed via bower, `bower install angular-chart.js --save`
2. added as dependency, `angular.module('myModule', ['chart.js']);`.

Documentation then recommends then adding `<script src="bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>`, but this file is not found if I add this line (think because using Rails).

Since the application is Angular ontop of Rails, I assume it needs to be added to Rails `application.js` file. As otherwise there is an angular `no module` error.

But I'm not sure exactly what needs to be added to application.js. I've tried:

- chart.js
- angular-chart.js
- angular-chart

(prefaced by `//= require`)

But everything results in a Rails error,

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Boards#index
couldn't find file 'chart.js' with type 'application/javascript'
```

Is there a way to find out exactly what needs to be added to `application.js`? Or some other way to solve this?

(Apologies if this is difficult to follow.)

Comment: try to use the gem `browsify`

Comment: Took a look - So `browserify-rails` allows you to just `require` the `bower`, `npm` packages in `application.js` without worrying about the Rails asset pipeline? (worried this is a little over my head)

Comment: yes that is that gem =)

Comment: Wooooow thats amazing! Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (as you mentioned in discussion) gem [`browserify-rails`](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails) to easily pick-up bower/node.js packages. Include gem into **Gemfile**, `bundle install`, and then install npm/bower package into app.

```
gem 'browserify-rails'
```